# How can I setup a moq mock to raise an event defined in an implementation of the interface and not the interface itself?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

The code to be mocked looks like this:

```
class Foo : IBar
{
    public virtual event EventHandler FooEventHandler;

    void FooMethod()
    {
        // blah, blah, blah...
    }

    void IBar.BarMethod()
    {
        this.FooEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs()); 
    }
}

interface IBar 
{
    void BarMethod();
}
```

I want to mock Foo and its implementation of IBar so that I can hand it to the subject under test and assert. Requirements tell me that I'm not allowed to put the event handler on the IBar interface, so [the explanation behind this link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqEvents_2.aspx) doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I'm trying to add clarity here, but I'm not sure it's working.

Using `Mock.As<T>()` method allows one to create a mock that follows multiple interfaces. With requirements that the event signature can't live on the `IBar` interface, I am mocking the concrete `Foo` class and then assigning `IBar` to the mock using `.As<IBar>()`. The return of `.As<IBar>` allows me to setup the `.BarMethod()` for raising an event with the `.Raises(...)` method accepting a lambda expression on the mock of `IBar`. In this expression, using `.As<Foo>()` allows access back to the virtual event handler on the concrete being mocked withing the context of setting up `IBar`.

```
var foo = new Mock<Foo>();
foo.As<IBar>()
   .Setup(bar => bar.BarMethod())
   .Raises(bar => bar.As<Foo>().FooEventHandler += null, new EventArgs());
```